# Why does the following string to number conversion fail in Matlab?

Tags: matlab

I'm trying to break up the date and add a single number to the day, month and year

```
date = input('Please enter the date (DD/MM/YYYY):','s')


tokens = regexp(sprintf(date),'/','split')
daymonthyear = str2num(tokens)
test = daymonthyear + 1
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As the error message indicates, `str2num` expects strings, not a cell array of strings. There are two ways to solve the issue. Either, you can use `str2double`, or `cellfun` combined with `str2num`.

Solution 1

```
daymonthyear = str2double(tokens)
```

Solution 2

```
daymonthyear = cellfun(@str2num,tokens)
```

Answer (score 1):

[Jonas already addressed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5958498/why-does-the-following-string-to-number-conversion-fail-in-matlab/5958523#5958523) the specific error you were getting, but I thought you may be interested in a simpler approach that uses [SSCANF](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/sscanf.html) instead of [REGEXP](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/regexp.html):

```
date = input('Please enter the date (DD/MM/YYYY):','s');
daymonthyear = sscanf(date,'%d/%d/%d',[1 3]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it using [addtodate](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/addtodate.html)?

```
i = input('Please enter the date (DD/MM/YYYY):','s')
date = datenum(i, 'dd/mm/yyyy')
date = addtodate(date, 1, 'year')
date = addtodate(date, 1, 'month')
date = addtodate(date, 1, 'day')
tokens = regexp(datestr(date, 'dd/mm/yyyy'),'/','split')
```

Comment: You should prefix your comment with a `%`, else MATLAB will return an error. Most probably you already knew this and used `//` for SO's comment highlighting to work (which doesn't recognize `%`). In that case, I'd suggest using `%#` or `%//`, which will then show the comment in grey.

Comment: @yoda: No worries. I removed it anyway because I changed my mind. Thanks for the tip! +1